# C# LINQ query creates unintended new row

Tags: c#, linq

I have the follow function that creates a new row or updates an existing row in model `MACReg` based on whether a given mac address exists.

```
public Boolean RegisterMAC(string pwd, string mac, string location)
{
    School school = getSchoolByCode(pwd);
    if (school == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //initial register or update
    using (CloudPrintDbContext db = new CloudPrintDbContext())
    {
        MACReg r = db.MACRegs.Find(mac);
        if (r == null) //create new row
        {
            MACReg m = new MACReg { MAC = mac, Location = location,
                School = school, RegTime = DateTime.Now, UpdateTime = DateTime.Now };
            db.MACRegs.Add(m);
        }
        else //update location
        {
            r.School = school;
            r.Location = location;
            r.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, the problem is that it always creates a new row in model `School` (not `MACReg`). Any idea why? Thanks!

Models for MACReg and School are below:

```
public class MACReg
{
    [Key]
    public string MAC { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public School School { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdateTime { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime RegTime { set; get; }
}

public class School
{
    [Key]
    public int SchoolID { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public string SchoolName { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateTime { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PwdExprTime { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] PwdHash { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] Salt { set; get; }
}
```

UPDATE: getSchoolByCode is below

```
private School getSchoolByCode(string pwd)
{
    using (CloudPrintDbContext db = new CloudPrintDbContext())
    {
        foreach(School s in db.Schools.Where(s => s.PwdExprTime > DateTime.Now)){
            byte[] userH = HashUtils.GenerateHash_Salt(pwd, s.Salt);
            if (HashUtils.CompareByteArrays(userH, s.PwdHash))
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you debug, what is the value of r?

Comment: Where is `school` coming from? It looks like it might come from outside the scope of the `db` context. Also this has (so far) nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: @L-Three r is an object that represents a row from db when a mac exists

Comment: he didn't ask what is r, he asked if it's always null. have you debugged your Project and watch the values of variables?

Comment: r is not null when mac exists. it holds values from db.

Comment: Let me clear things a bit, Is it the problem actually about School object is getting created repeatedly? Not about the MACReg object. Can you give the code where School object is created.

Comment: @Rawling sorry about misuing LINQ. I thought accessing db from C# all has to do with LINQ. how should I call this? btw, i've just added entire function.

Comment: Show `getSchoolByCode()`.

Comment: I'm almost certain of it that `getSchoolByCode` creates a new `School` object and that EF saves it as a new object everytime. But as @CodeCaster said above, show `getSchoolByCode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `school` is from a different `CloudPrintDbContext` so it's not tracked by the `db` instance in the `using` statement. If it isn't attached to any other `DbContext` then you could attach it to that one before you set the `School` and then it should work.

```
db.Schools.Attach(school);
```

As an aside I'd recommend you use the `DbSet.Create()` method instead of `new` so that you can use the dynamic proxies, as per [EF documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx).

Comment: thanks! do you mean that `school` instance is not recognized in `RegisterMAC`, so it's created again? also, do you mean to put `db.Schools.Attach(school)` in RegisterMAC before `MACReg r = db.MACRegs.Find(mac)`? but where to attach `mac`? I have to `Find` an instance of `MACReg` first, right?

Comment: @dragon_cat Sorry I just saw that MAC is a string. Thought it was another entity.

Comment: @dragon_cat EF doesn't know that the `school` is an existing entity so it thinks it's a new one. When you call `db.MACRegs.Add(m)` it will also add the `school`.